# .htaccess rewrite commands acting not as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ about.html [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L]

# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200

# Map new URI to file
RewriteRule code/(.*) code.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**first rule** replace about with about.html - works

**second rule**
should have allowed me to write `www.example.com/test-me` - but when I var_dump `$_GET["url"]` I get: `index.php` while I expected `$_GET["url"]` to return `test-me`.

**third rule:**
not working - return 404 error. I expected file `code.php` on root to return with `id` as a URL param.

What I am trying to achieve is that when someone types `www.example.com/lesson/lesson-name` this will trigger the file `code.php` on the root and plant `lesson-name` as `$_GET['lesson_name']`
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second rule is triggering a the rewrite engine to start over and since you have no preceding condition (unlike the directive below) it ends up rewriting `index.php` on the second pass.

Your directives are also in the wrong order. The second rule that catches *everything* needs to go last. However, as stated, this rule catches *everything* - including all requests for static resources etc. So, you'll probably need additional conditions to prevent this.

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about$ about.html [NC]

# Map "/lesson/<lesson-name>" to "/code.php?lesson_name=<lesson-name>"
RewriteRule ^lesson/(.*) code.php?lesson_name=$1 [L]

# Map everything else - for example "/index.php?url=test-me"
# Exclude static resources
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thank you. this works but for some reason I an unable to get $_GET["lesson_name"] although var_dumping $_GET returns: 

array(1) {
  ["lesson_name"]=>
  string(9) "my-lesson"
}

Comment: I'd mistakenly used a hyphen instead of an underscore in the URL parameter name in the rule in my answer (now corrected). Although you appear to have changed this, according to your var dump, so this should work OK?

Comment: I changed it in the htaccess file. I see the param in the var_dump. Just gets no value when called with param-name

Comment: Hhhmmm, that doesn't really make sense, since the value is right there in the "var dump" of the `$_GET` array? Are you checking `$_GET['lesson_name']` at the same place in the code? Or are you checking this later and _something else_ has perhaps overwritten this value? When you call `$_GET['lesson_name']` is the array index _set_? Or is it _set_, but _empty_?